# Problemas para agregar una nueva fila a un origen de datos en Visual C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

Estoy creando un sistema de ventas y estoy trabajando con origenes de datos (Dataset, DataSource etc.) y actualmente presento problemas a la hora de insertar un nuevo registro/fila a mi base de datos, el codigo que utilizo para agregar un registro es el siguiente:

```
   private void btn_agregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataTable dt = bindingSource1.DataSource as DataTable;
        if (dt!= null)

        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();

            row["codigo"] = txt_codigo.Text;
            row["descripcion"] = txt_descripcion.Text;
            row["categoria"] = txt_categoria.Text;
            row["precio1"] = txt_precio_usd.Text;
            row["precio2"] = txt_precio_bs.Text;

            dt.Rows.Add(row);

            bindingSource1.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
```

El codigo mostrado, literal, no hace nada, no salen errores en el Visual Studio, simplemente no funciona, no añade el nuevo registro a la BD, al presionar el boton no ocurre nada.

Utlizo el control BindingSource para tener acceso al DataSource (que en mi proyecto es databaseDataSet.xsd) los datos se visualizan en el formulario principal en un DataGridView y se añaden los registros desde otro formulario, pero como dije anteriormente no ocurre nada...

Si estoy errado, si tengo alguna falla en la logica agradeceria su apoyo colegas para resolver este problema, infinitamente agradecido con su ayuda!

Comment: Hola, podrías decir si la respuesta dada te resultó útil, gracias

Comment: Buenas noches, no amigo, no me resulto, coloco lo que dices y sigue sin añadir nuevos registros. Gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Después que añades la nueva fila al **DataTable** deberias poner:

```
dt.AcceptChanges();
```

Este método permite que el **DataTable** guarde cualquier cambio que se haya realizado.

Para rechazar cambios hechos en el **DataTable** pon:

```
dt.RejectChanges();
```